# How can I understand the android broadcast receiver via easy way?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I want to use android broadcast receiver in my application but I don't know exactly how to use the android broadcast receiver and how it is work in an android application.I found the many definition for this in Google but I didn't know exactly what did they mean.

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html

Comment: "I want to use android broadcast receiver in my application" -- why? Most applications do not need one. Do not use classes just because you feel like using those classes. Use classes when they solve some specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

With [broadcast receivers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) you can either hook into system broadcast such as Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_LOW or you can create your own broadcasts. Why would you want to do this? Because broadcasts allow you to exchange information between your component and to have a loose coupling between them at the same time. A component which broadcasts a message does not need to know about the listeners and no registering of the listener is required. This allows you to implement the [message passing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_passing) pattern in your Android application.

You can create your own broadcasts either for interprocess communication, or you can use an optimized version for communicating inside the current process through the LocalBroadcastManager class.

The link given by Tim Castelijns will give you some examples.